# In block swap algorithm for else case how come arguments for leftrotate are arr+n-d

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm unable to interpret how come we are giving `arr []` as `arr+n-d` in the `leftrotate` function. The comment `HERE` marks the line I'm talking about.

**Block swap algorithm**:

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size);
void swap(int arr[], int fi, int si, int d);

void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
{ 
    if(d == 0 || d == n)
        return;

    if(n-d == d)
    {
        swap(arr, 0, n-d, d);   
        return;
    }  

    if(d < n-d)
    {  
        swap(arr, 0, n-d, d);
        leftRotate(arr, d, n-d);    
    }  
    else            
    {
        swap(arr, 0, d, n-d);
        leftRotate(arr+n-d, 2*d-n, d); // HERE
    }
}

void swap(int arr[], int fi, int si, int d)
{
    int i, temp;

    for(i = 0;i<d;i++)   
    {
        temp = arr[fi + i];
        arr[fi + i] = arr[si + i];
        arr[si + i] = temp;
    }     
}
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/block-swap-algorithm-for-array-rotation/

Comment: `arr+n-d` is infact `&arr[n-d]`

Comment: Note this doesn't work in most languages, only C and C++, and it's poor style in C++, so it should probably be tagged C. (Well, and with some rewriting in BCPL -- if you have that.)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass an array as a parameter, only the address of that array is passed. You can read about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-arrays-are-passed-to-functions-in-cc/)

Suppose you have declared an array arr as `int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`

Now if you call `printf(arr);`  It returns the base address of `arr` (address of starting element of array)

If you type `printf(arr[i])` the compiler interprets `arr[i]` as `*(arr + i)` and returns the value at address `arr + i`.
Arrays in C\C++ are accessed using pointer arithmetic.

Now coming to your question:

```
leftRotate(arr+n-d, 2*d-n, d); // HERE
```

We recursively call `leftRotate()` because we have shifted the B part of array with Al. Now the B part is at its final location and we can forget about it.

We now focus our attention on arr starting from element arr[n-d] to put those elements at their correct place.
So, the first argument of above function gives the address of element arr[n-d] and like dave_thompson_085 commented it's a bad practice because the type of that argument is not explicitly mentioned.

The second argument gives us the number of elements remaining to be shifted and the third argument gives us the size of array.

You can read more about arrays and pointers here:

[Difference between pointer and array in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-pointer-array-c/)

[Pointer vs Array in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-vs-array-in-c/)

[Arrays, String Constants and Pointers](https://icecube.wisc.edu/%7Edglo/c_class/array_ptr.html)